# Sony Vaio External Monitor problems

Tags: 14.04, ati, xorg, multiple-monitors, vaio

I am having problems enabling external monitor on my Sony Vaio notebook. It is being successfully detected, but when I try to enable second external monitor the screen glitches and lags (it is like video driver is not working properly) and nothing is displayed on second monitor. When I use external monitor only all seems to be better - no flickering and glitching, but when I try to extend the problems begin. I use proprietary fglrx-update drivers. Here is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1440 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900       59.9 +
   1440x900       59.9* 
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0*    59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1152x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And here is my Xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "amd-layout"
    Screen      0  "amd-screen" 0 0
    Screen         "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1" RightOf "amd-screen"
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "amd-monitor"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "intel"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    BusID       "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amd-device"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen      1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amd-screen"
    Device     "amd-device"
    Monitor    "amd-monitor"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-1"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-1"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

*UPDATE*

I have managed to get it working over VGA with the following command:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --right-of LVDS1 --output VGA1 --scale 1.0001x1.0001
```

Still, it does not work over HDMI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, xrandr's --scale option is fixing the flickering image. After that, to fix the "No Signal" problem I needed to open Displays settings app and drag external monitor around my built-in monitor to some arbitrary position and hit apply, then it all started to work.